# Почему java date странно работает?

Tags: java, дата

У меня есть класс, при создании которого начинается отсчет времени

```
 public someclass(int minutes) {
        this.timeout = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + minutes * 60 * 1000);
    }
```

и метод, который проверяет, не закончилось ли время

```
   public static void update() {
(работает каждые 5 секунд)
        Iterator<someclass> .. = iterator
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Someclass class = iterator.next();
            if (new Date().after(class.getDeadLine())) {
               /// выполняются действия
            }
        }
    }

  public Date getDeadLine() {
        return timeout;
    }
```

Проблема в том, что все вроде бы прекрасно работает, но когда я передаю в конструктор 200000 минут, то все ломается, то есть действия выполняются почти моментально, а не после 200000 минут, в чем может быть проблема? Или чем я могу заменить Date, потому что я так поняла, что проблема именно в date, а не в моем коде. (может и нет, но это так выглядит)

Кстати, еще в моем коде создается SimpleDateFormat по таймауту и там я тоже заметила, что оно неправильно сохраняется.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

200 000 * 60 * 1000 больше чем может поместиться в int, вам надо тогда написать minutes сделать типа long и написать явно minutes * 60L * 1000L, чтоб оно в int не переводило